# SQL Statement - How to find the newest entry WHERE

Tags: sql

I try to use the MAX function in the WHERE Clause, but do not get the right solution for the problem:

**Table: guest**

```
dateTime | ID-A | ID-B | leaveTime
```

**Problem:** Update the leaveTime where the dateTime is the newest and the ID-A = 'dog' AND ID-B ='CAT'
AND leaveTime is Empty.

```
UPDATE `guest` SET `leaveTime`='2020-08-20 13:00:06' WHERE SELECT(MAX(dateTime) AND ID-A= 5 AND ID-B= 1001);
```

I know this syntax is wrong, but I don't exactly how to adress the max-value, or should I use HAVING instead ?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Instead of using the MAX function I found a solution with ORDER BY: UPDATE `guest` SET `leaveTime`= '2020-08-20 13:00:06' WHERE ID-A = 5 AND ID-B = 1001 AND leave_time IS NULL ORDER BY dateTime DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: . . That works in few databases.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try!!

```
UPDATE `guest` SET `leaveTime`='2020-08-20 13:00:06' WHERE dateTime in
(SELECT dateTime FROM guest where ID-A= 5 AND ID-B= 1001 ORDER BY dateTime desc LIMIT 1) and ID-A= 5 AND ID-B= 1001
```